# How i add my archtype to the maven central archetype-catalog.xml

Tags: maven, archetypes

i build some archtypes and deploy them on maven central, but there doesn't appear in the maven remote archetype-catalog.xml (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml).

What should i do to add my archtypes to the maven central archtype-catalog?

Answer (score 1):

You just have to deploy your archetype (as archetype packaging type), then central will automatically update its archetype catalog few hours after...